Wooden ductwork ok for kitchen vent?
We have a cabinet mounted microwave that acts as the vent for our stove. The old external vent cover let rain in to the microwave so we replaced both.
We hired a handyman to mount a new microwave, replace the water damaged bottom of the cabinet it's mounted to and reconnect the vent. However, he used wood to connect the vent instead of metal ductwork. Is wood a viable solution for microhood ductwork?
To clarify, we used metal going from the outside vent, through the wall to inside the cabinet. But our handyman then used wood to connect this to the microwave.

I'd be wary of the fire hazard, as wood absorbs sprayed fat from frying. Could you line the wood with metal, either sheet metal or a duct?

I'd also be worried about moisture - steam could easily condense on the wood and cause problems.

Wood does tend to absorb moisture and smells.  Wood is usually only used if shown, since it is usually more expensive than metal work.  You should not be worried about heat from a microwave, but smells after a time might be an issue..

Short answer, NO. The connection must be all metal.
There are numerous metal ducts available that are sized for range ducting. Plenty of adapters for microwaves if needed. There is no reason to use wood unless it is ignorance or laziness.
